# Encog: incremental training

Tags: neural-network, encog, supervised-learning

I came across this question ([Encog: BasicNetwork: Online learning without preconstructed dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126413/encog-basicnetwork-online-learning-without-preconstructed-dataset/31807910)) about online learning for neural networks using Encog. I would like to ask a related question. Let's say I have x number of data points to train a neural network. After training, I got y number of new data points. The idea is to have a neural network using x+y data points. Yet, since these x points are already used for training a network, is it ok to train the same network with these y data points without any reset and have the effect as if the network is trained using both x and y data points, not to spend time to re-train everything from scratch. Or is it done with this: https://github.com/encog/encog-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/examples/neural/resume/TrainResume.java ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the right thing is to use the TrainingContinuation as it carries over some information about the training. However, if you are not serializing and then loading the network you might be able to skip it by not calling train.finalize(). This of course depends on the training method you are using and YMMV.

Comment: I didn't quite get the idea of TrainingContinuation for my case.  If you want to stop training and continue later on the exact same dataset, it makes sense to use such a function. However, when you want to train, the already trained network, with a new dataset (so like old dataset + new dataset), I doubt that TrainingContinuation makes any job. In the following case, it looks like training continues but with a new dataset not old dataset + new dataset, so, earlier training is lost, right? nnlearner.resume(trainContinuation);
nnlearner.setTraining(newTrainingSet);

Comment: If you want to use the sum of both training sets, you would have to pass the combination of both to setTrainingSet(). What you would get otherwise is that the old dataset is replaced, but the trained weights are kept, and would be subsequently trained only on the new datset.

Comment: Then, training becomes too expensive, which is something I would like to avoid. So, it is not possible to do that.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're expecting here. Do you want to train on both sets at the same time or do you want to train on one set, retain the weights, then train on the next?

Comment: It is to train on training set A first, then train on A+B, then train on A+B+C, etc.  As it is expected this can be expensive. Thus, I wanted to learn whether it is possible to just train on B (after training on A only) as if training was performed on A+B, then train on C like A+B+C

Comment: This is not really specific to Encog. You need to think about how training works: you are presenting an example and propagating the error backwards to change the weights in the network. You can do this in whichever order you want on your training sets, but if you present one set first, then another, it won't be the same as doing one then both. Your starting point after training with A will be the same, but what happens after will be different. It may or may not give similar results, but you need to test that and it depends on the datasets.

Comment: I am aware of that. That's why I asked the question on encog specifically not on neural network after finding out encog has training continuation capability.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the meaning of continuation in this context.It is not intended in the functional programming sense of continuation, but just as a device to allow the training to resume. It would be just the same as if you replaced the training set in between two epochs.

Comment: Yes, I know. In the beginning, I just expected that continuation should be doing something fancy :) other than just really continuing training

Comment: Nope, it does just that. It's useful if you want to serialize a network and continue training after deserializing though.